# Show a group of order 60 is simple.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am given that $G$ is a group of order $60$, with $20$ elements of order $3$, $24$ elements of order $5$ and $15$ elements of order $2$. I have to show that $G$ is isomorphic to $A_5$.

I think that the best way to go about this is to prove that $G$ is itself simple, rather than list out the elements of $A_5$, and then it just follows that it is isomorphic to $A_5$, but this where I am stuck. I have tried using Sylow's Theorem to show there are no normal subgroups but to no avail.

I would appreciate if someone could help me or even point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: The Sylow theorems would only tell you about the groups of order $4$, $3$ and $5$. They say nothing of whether a normal subgroup of order, say, $10$ exists.

Comment: There is no elements of order 10 in my group though.

Comment: @Crockett There are elements of order 5 and order 2 though, so you could have a super group isomorphic to $D_{10}$. (In fact there will be one, but it won't be normal)

Comment: If there was a normal subgroup of order $10$ then it would have a normal Sylow $5$-subgroup, which would be normal in $G$, which you know is false. The same contradiction applies to normal subgroups of order $20$, $15$ or $30$. Similarly, a normal subgroup of order $12$ would have eithe ra unique Sylow $2$-subgroup or a unique Sylow $3$=subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

(1) There are more than one Sylow-$2$ subgroups (order $4$). [Hint: see no. of elements of order $2$].

(2) Let $H_1,H_2$ be two (abelian) Sylow-$2$ subgroups. Suppose they intersect non-trivially. Then $|H_1\cap H_2|=2$.

- (2.1) Let $x\in H_1\cap H_2$ with $x\neq 1$. Show: $|C_G(x)|\geq 8$. [Hint $C_G(x)\supseteq H_i$]
- (2.2) Show $|C_G(x)|$ can not be $8$ (Hint: what is order of $G$?)
- (2.3) Note that $C_G(x)$ contains $H_1$ so $|H_1|$ divides $|C_G(x)|$. By (2.1) and (2.2), show $3$ or $5$ divides $|C_G(x)|$.
- (2.4) $C_G(x)$ contains an element of order $3$ or $5$, say $z$. Then order of $xz$ is $2.3$ or $2.5$, contradiction; why? [see hypothesis].

(3) Show that any two Sylow-$2$ subgroups intersect trivially; each contains $3$ elements of order $2$. Deduce that there are exactly $5$ Sylow-$2$ subgroups.

(4) Let $H_1,H_2,H_3,H_4,H_5$ be the five Sylow-$2$ subgroups. $G$ acts on them by conjugation, and transitively (why?) [Hint: Recall Sylow's theorems]

(5) Thus we get a homomorphism from $G$ to $S_5$. The order of image is at least $5$ (there is $g_i$ taking $H_1$ to $H_i$, $i=1,2,3,4,5$). Hence order of kernel is at most $12$.

(6) By arguments of Derek Holt in comment, deduce that kernel should be trivial.

(7) Deduce that $G$ is isomorphic to subgroup of $S_5$.

(8) Take a long breath!!!!